# How do we access a parent record when using SObject?

Tags: apex, soql

I have junction object (`Junction__c`) with two master-detail relationships to 'contacts' and 'Training_Session__c'. I'm trying to write a query to generate a list of email addresses for use in a visual force page. Here's what the APEX class looks like.

```
   List<SObject> contact_list = [SELECT id, contact__r.email, contact__r.name FROM Junction__c WHERE Training_Seesion__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

Mapping the values of a result (getPopulatedfiedldsAsMap()) returns:

```
Contact_list field name is Id, value is a0C3D0000007x2jUAA
Contact_list field name is Contact__c, value is 0033D00000NopQPQAZ
Contact_list field name is CurrencyIsoCode, value is USD
Contact_list field name is Contact__r, value is Contact: {Email=ronnidadamo@cuvox.de, Name=Ronni Adamo, Id=0033D00000NopQPQAZ, CurrencyIsoCode=USD}
```

I'm struggling with the proper syntax to access contact_list.contact__r [(contact or contact__c)].email. Whenever attempting to access the value in a loop, the code fails to compile with

```
Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: contact__r
```

Comment: Can you post your for loop? Why are you querying into a generic `SObject`?

Comment: If you used the type `Junction__c` you would have access to the field `contact__r`, but since its a generic type, you need to use `getSObject`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a generic SObject, you need to use getSObject:

```
for(SObject record: contact_list) {
  Contact conRecord = record.getSObject('Contact__r');
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Fox! 

     addresses = (string) contact_IDs.getsobject('contact__r').get('email');

did the trick.